# Change Segmented Controller properties in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, uisegmentedcontrol, picker

I'm trying to create a Segmented Controller in SwiftUI. This is my code so far:

```
Picker(selection: $currentStatus, label: Text("Treatment Status")) {
            ForEach(status, id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image]

This is fine, but I'd like to change the Segmented Controller properties to make it look like this:

[image]

I tried looking up any tutorials on how to modify Segmented Controllers in SwiftUI but couldn't find anything. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: It is not allowed for now to change SegmentedPickerStyle, just implement your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a view that looks like the above and acts like a picker, see if this will work:

```
struct MinimalPickerView: View {
        @State var selected = "Pendiente"
        let labels = ["Pendiente", "Atendido", "Cancelado", "Ausente"]
    
        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                ForEach(labels, id: \.self) { label in
                    VStack {
                        Text(label).padding(2)
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(height: 7)
                            .foregroundColor((selected == label) ? .black : .clear)
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selected = label
                    }
                    .padding(2)
                }
            }
        }

}
```